# Linking a tracked Event with Goal conversions or Ecommerce transactions in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a goal conversion set up that tracks hits on my site's receipt page, basically to know how many people made successful transactions. I've also set up ecommerce tracking for this page so I have both goals and ecommerce.

One of the ways the site boosts sales is through a small interactive widget that guides users to which product best fits them. I've set up events tracking for that widget to track user click-throughs there.

Now I want to link the 2 together and find out how many goal conversions/ecommerce transactions passed through the interactive widget. Basically, I want to track how many conversions I got from that widget click event.

Is there a built-in way to do this using GA without touching application code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jensen**, I am afraid events are not the best option to analyze this.

The reason for that is that you are dealing with various scopes (goal/e-com transaction have a scope of session, whereas events of page). See this [brilliant article by Avinash](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/hits-sessions-metrics-dimensions-web-analytics/).

What this all means is that if you look at the report Jensen suggests, you might get wrong assumptions. What you will see is that if a visit ended up with $2,000 transaction and events A, B and C were triggered, **then all of them will be assigned $2,000** "value".

That's the reason why the total e-commerce revenue will be **bloated** in this report if you compared it to the numbers in the dedicated e-commerce reports. See this screenshot (sorry for blurring some parts):

[image]

Much better way to do this is creating various segments for visits/users and then comparing the overall performance (conversion rate, number of products bought, average sale amount etc.).

Those segments might be tricky as well (I don't know the specific details about your website), but they might actually give you some answers.

Few suggestions:

- visits that used the up-sell features and ended-up converting
- visits that used the up-sell features and ended-up **NOT** converting

And various other combinations, the new segment builder is quite powerful (even allows you to use consequent steps). It will take some time, and make sure that every single time before diving into the reports and numbers, you always **have hypothesis that you are trying to validate**.

In other words -- think twice, analyze once :-). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the details and the informative link. I guess I need to rethink my approach regarding these metrics.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a bit embarassing. I was looking around the GA views trying to see how I can do this and I found the answer myself.

It's very simple, just go to Behavior > Events > Top Events, then on the Explorer section, click on "Ecommerce". This will show a view that includes the top events and their transaction/ecommerce details.

[image: Top Events View]

Comment: those numbers might not be that accurate and easy to get as it seems, please see my answer